# SimpleAudioEngine file path crash

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I'm trying to play a .caf file using simpleaudioengine but I get an exception every time I try to reference the file. The compiler gives me the following: 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'.

I think it's caused by an invalid file path, but I'm not sure how to fix it. I dragged the file into the resource folder in Xcode and confirmed it was included in my project folder.

This is the first time I've used simpleaudioengine in my project. The only lines I've added are the import at the top and this:

```
[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playBackgroundMusic:@"bgMusic2.caf"];
```

Comment: just fyi it's unusual to use caf for music, it should be an mp3

Comment: Make sure it is included in your Bundle resources, goto [project name]->[target name]->Build Phases->Copy Bundle Resources. If not add it there and it should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure your sound `bgMusic2.caf` is included in your bundle resources,

Add your music file to

**`[project name]`->`[target name]`->Build Phases->Copy Bundle Resources**

And it should work without a problem.